# About a restatement of the Bloch theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals

In the *Introduction to Solid State Physics* written by Charles Kittel, chapter 7, restatement of the Bloch theorem, Kittel says the wave function can be represented as follows:
$$\psi_k(x) = \sum_G C(k-G) e^{i(k-G)x},$$
where $k$ represents the wave vector, and $G$ is a reciprocal lattice vector.

He says this is another way to express the original wave function $\psi = \sum_k C(k) e^{ikx}$ once we determine the $C$ from the central equation.

However, I feel it is difficult to understand the logic here. If we decompose the original wave function as $\psi = \sum_k \psi_k$, then we have:
$$\psi_k = C(k) e^{ikx}.$$
Then I can't see why $C(k) e^{ikx} = \sum_G C(k-G) e^{i(k-G)x}$. And actually I don't understand why we can reach the first equation once we can determine $C$ from the central equation. I feel there is a big leap of logic here on the part of Kittel.

The only possible solution which I can come up with is that the $k$ in the original wave function refers to the $k$ over all the space, and the $k$ in the first equation is restricted in the first Brillouin zone. Then it would be very strange why Kittel did not clearly mention it.